# AzureDevops Pipelines ArtifactoryGenericDownload@3, no Endpoint

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, artifactory

When using ArtifactoryGenericDownload@3 in AzureDevops YML pipelines, I receive the error:

> Endpoint not present: undefined

even though my service connection is correctly configured. The JFrog / Aritfactory Documentation doesn't seem to mention examples of the usage of ArtifactoryGenericDownload at all, are there any examples of how to use and configure.

My current pipeline setup looks like this:

```yaml
    stages:
  - stage:
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
          - task: ArtifactoryGenericDownload@3
            inputs:
              artifactoryService: 'service-connection'
              filePattern: ${{parameters.filePattern}}
              downloadPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
              flatDownload: true
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the parameter name "artifactoryService" to "connection", worked for me.

Comment: did you just found out by trying or is there any docs your aware of ?

Comment: I've had a pipeline example running with that but I could not find the doc used indeed, which is quite annoying.